# Is it possible to add new functions to PHP?

Tags: php, function, configuration-files

I would like to add a function to PHP so I can use it in any script that runs on my server. Is it possible to register a function like if it was native from PHP? Does PHP has some kind of configuration file where I can register new global / native functions?

There is no  intentions to use it in production, I'm just curious on how to achieve this.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php

Comment: @ajreal: What do you want to tell us?

Comment: @ajreal: What does turning PHP into C++ have to do with this?

Comment: write your php code and make use hiphop to compile into native php function

Comment: Native _means_ you did not add it. So.... no.

Comment: really? maybe i misunderstood the native

Comment: @ajreal: That's not what HipHop does... all it does is turn existing PHP code into C++ code that can be compiled and run outside the PHP interpreter. It doesn't turn PHP code into native PHP extensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a "Global include" (defined in php.ini)

Read this (php.net manual)

[auto-append-file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-append-file) and [auto-prepend-file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file)

Comment: that's exactly what I was looking for, answer accepted (it seems your answer was the first one ;)

Answer (score 5):

You can write [extensions in C or C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632160/how-to-make-a-php-extension), in particular write or use library bindings with [SWIG or FFI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152584/is-there-anything-like-pythons-ctype-for-php-accessing-libraries-without-the-n). But that's a bit effort, and only advisable if you meant compiled "native" functions.

The lazy option to add new core functions to PHP via config is the [`auto_prepend_file=`](http://php.net/auto_prepend_file) `php.ini` setting. That allows to register a script that gets executed before everything else. (I use that for fixing magic quotes on some servers, or always having phpquery available for CLI testing.)

Answer (score 4):

There is a full chapter in the manual http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.php devoted to writing extensions to php, with examples.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to write them in PHP and include them before your scripts is executed using

```
auto_prepend_file = /path/to/file.php
```

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

else you need to learn C and write a extension